# Cómo obtener el context desde un DialogFrament

Tags: android-fragment, spinner, xamarin.android

Este es el código con el que lleno los *Spinners* en los *activities*, pero en una clase que hereda de `DialogFragment`. Ahora bien, no sé cómo obtener el contexto desde en un `DialogFrament`.

```
public void LoadProveedorParametro(Spinner spnProveedorPopUp)
{
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "kobit.db3");
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    var tblProveedor = db.Table<Temporada>().Where(x => x.Borrado == false).OrderBy(x => x.Nombre);
    ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();

    foreach (var prove in tblProveedor)
    {
        LstTemporada.Add(prove);
        lst.Add(prove.Nombre);
    }
    //Aquí es el problema
    string[] arr = (String[])lst.ToArray(typeof(string));
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, // no es un contexto
            Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, arr);
            spnProveedorPopUp.Adapter = adapter;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DialogFragment` hereda de `Fragment`. `Fragment` tiene una propiedad llamada `Activity` y como ya sabemos, un `Activity` ***es*** un `Context`, por lo puedes enviarle como parametro la propiedad `Activity` de `Fragment`:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                          new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.Activity, 
 Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, arr);
                spnProveedorPopUp.Adapter = adapter;
```

.

Comment: Perfecto @Einer, gracias por la gran ayuda